# Java: cannot read from socket, thread gets stuck on readLine()

Tags: java, sockets, stream

Here is my code for the server side:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    String message;
    String command;
    String[] arguments;

    try{
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                        clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while(online){
            message = inStream.readLine();

            if(message == null)
                continue;

            if(message.charAt(0) == '/'){
                int endOfCommandIndex = message.indexOf(' ');
                command = message.substring(1, endOfCommandIndex);
                arguments = message.substring(endOfCommandIndex + 1).split(" ");

                if(command.equals("login")){
                    setUserName(arguments[0]);
                    setName(arguments[0]);

                    sendMessage(this, "Connected");
                }
                //....
          }
     }
}
```

As mentioned in the title, the thread gets stuck reading from the InputStream of the Socket (I checked with JDB and it's not a conditional waiting because it appears to be still "running").

I tried to write a line to the socket but it doesn't change its state at all. I'm trying to build a chat-like local application and I'm quite new to socket and streams. Thanks in advance.

For the client side:

```
String msg;
try{
    while(!((msg = stdIn.readLine()).equals("/quit")))
        toServer.println(msg);
}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In case someone wants review my entire code, [it is here hosted on github](https://github.com/UMR1352/MultiUserChat)

Comment: "A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF)."; is one being sent?

Comment: @JacobG. Yeah i think so. I'm writing to the socket using a PrintWriter attached to the output stream of the client socket using the method println(). So yeah. I guess

Comment: Thanks @RannLifshitz for the Revisions!

Comment: @EnricoMarconi You are more then welcome. Feel free to contribute to StackOverflow as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the message is never flushed after being written into the socket stream.

Try either call:

```
toServer.flush();
```

after `println`, or enable auto flushing when constructing `toServer`:

```
toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```